# How to get consistent shape name when adding new slides?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a macro that lets me insert text in a text box in all slides, based on my excel file. The problem is that when I insert a new slide with a placeholder the shapes in that new slide is renamed with a different number, even when I name them in the slide master. Is there a way for the shapes to keep their name when I insert a new slide?

Example:

My PPT VBA code:

```
Slide.Shapes("Title 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = blablabla
Slide.Shapes("Subtitle 2").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = blablabla
```

In my slide master, I have named my shapes "Title 1" and "Subtitle 2" respectively.

After I exited slide master, I add a new slide (note: not duplicate slide). However, it became "Title 3" and "Subtitle 4". The numbering will be different.

Appreciate your advise on how to keep the Name same when we add a new slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to do this automatically you need to create event procedure. First in VBE you add a class module, name it clsAppEvents and add code

```
' Class module clsAppEvents 
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents App As Application

Sub App_PresentationNewSlide(ByVal oSld As Slide)
  ' Add your code here e.g.
  oSld.Shapes(1).Name = "Title 1"
  oSld.Shapes(2).Name = "Subtitle 2"
End Sub
```

Then in your Module1 add this

```
' Module code
Option Explicit

Public oAppEvents As New clsAppEvents

Sub InitialiseApp()
    Set oAppEvents.App = Application
End Sub
```

Now if you run InitialiseApp() (once is enough) every time you add new slide your Sub App_PresentationNewSlide will execute. (In event class you may further define other events procedures too).